# How do I add appcompat-v7:27.0.1 to SDK?

Tags: android, react-native, configuration, android-appcompat

I have this error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs0Tm.png)

I think its happening because my SDK hasn't appcompat-v7:27.0.1 version. I dont know how add this version to my SDK. I need help!

[My appcompat-v7 folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTlu6.png)

I paste relevant code below. If you see the error elsewhere, tell me please!:

/app/build.gradle

```
  android {
      compileSdkVersion 23
      buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.reactnavigationdrawer"
          minSdkVersion 16
          targetSdkVersion 22
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
          ndk {
              abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
          }
      }
      ...
 }
  dependencies {
      compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
      compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
      compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1"
      compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
      compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:+'
  }
```

build.gradle

```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

          // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
          // in the individual module build.gradle files
      }
  }

  allprojects {
      repositories {
          mavenLocal()
          jcenter()
          mavenCentral()
          maven {
              // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
              url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Support library should not use a different version than the compileSdkVersion  23. Use ` com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0'`

Comment: if I change compileSdkVersion  to 27 the error continues because in my SKD dont find appcompat:27.0.1 version. I need to know how to add it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I answered it with the next config:

/app/build.gradle

```
     android {
      compileSdkVersion 27
      buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.reactnavigationdrawer"
          minSdkVersion 16
          targetSdkVersion 22
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
          ndk {
              abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
          }
      }
      signingConfigs {
         release {
             storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
             storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
             keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
             keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
         }
     }
     ...
    dependencies {
      compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
      compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
      compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+"
      compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
      compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')) {
       exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
      }
      compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')
   }
```

build.gradle

```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

          // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
          // in the individual module build.gradle files
      }
  }

  allprojects {
      repositories {
          mavenLocal()
          jcenter()
          mavenCentral()
          maven {
              // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
              url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
          }
          maven {url"https://maven.google.com"}
          configurations.all {
              resolutionStrategy {
                  force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Dont forget add string.xml and its corresponding  in AndroidManifest.xml before executing:

> cd android
>
> gradlew clean
>
> cd ..
>
> react-native run-android

Comment: Dont forget add string.xml and its corresponding in AndroidManifest.xml. What is to add and where?

Comment: You can find it in .\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml

Comment: strings.xml is used to declare global strings that you call from AndoidManifest to catch the app name for example "android:label="@string/app_name""

Comment: string.xml example:

Comment: <resources>
    <string name="app_name">Manolo App</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">69</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">69</string>
</resources>

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your issue,
If your compileSdkVersion is 23, You can not add that dependency.
Try one of these:
1. Install SDK Plaform 27 by selecting `Tool` > `Android` > `SDK Manager`> check Android API 27. next switch to `SDK Tool`>`Show Package Details` check one of the sdk build-tools version 27 and `Apply`
Then edit build.gradle: change compileSdkVersion to `compileSdkVersion 27`.
You should also change buildToolsVersion to "27.x.x" for example is `buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'`

OR
2. Try compile dependency `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1` to the version you are having.

You may want to see something here [Android studio failed to build tools after updating to 3.0 from 2.3 stable channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007220/android-studio-failed-to-build-tools-after-updating-to-3-0-from-2-3-stable-chann/48087758#48087758)